# yii2 action colum hidden still visible

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I want to hide a column in my gridview using kartik gridview.
But when i do something like that :

```
$gridColumns = [
[
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\DataColumn',
    'attribute'=>'name', 
    'hidden' => 'true',
],
```

My column is still visible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`visible`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$visible-detail) instead:

```
`visible` => false
```

Comment: `hidden` should work too, the only difference is that with `hidden` the column is shown if you export the table to a file

Answer (score 2):

It is a boolean column, not a string. You should put:

```
'hidden' => true,
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it and old question, but I wanted to add that if you want columns to be hidden in grid, but available for export use `'hidden' => false` instead of `'visble' => true`